# Can I connect to my Windows machine from my Mac without a VM?

Tags: windows-7, macos

Is there any way I can connect (Terminal) into my Windows machine from my Mac without having to go through a virtual machine?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do on your Windows machine?

Comment: If I use parallels (VM) I can fireup a windows o/s, and the RDP (mstsc) into my windows machine, I was hoping I could do this natively from Mac lion somehow.

Answer (score 2):

There's a myriad of ways to do this.  If you want the quick and dirty way, if your guest VM is Windows 7, then just enable the [Telnet Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732046%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  Another good one is [freeSSHd for Windows](http://www.freesshd.com/).

My personal choice is Cygwin with SSHd.  It's a pain but if you follow [this](http://pigtail.net/LRP/printsrv/cygwin-sshd.html) and [this](http://www.kgx.net.nz/2010/03/cygwin-sshd-and-windows-7/), you'll be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The best way to do so is either via RDP (I don't know if Mac has a built in RDP client, but there are many free-to-download RDP clients) or use a VNC server running on your windows machine and a VNC viewer/client on your Mac.

VNC and RDP will allow you to "remote" into your Windows machine and you'll be able to interact with your Windows desktop from inside the window on your Mac.

Comment: I think the OP wanted terminal access.

Comment: In which case SSH (secure) or Telnet (insecure) are the obvious choices, and I'm a bit surprised that he even needed to ask :/

Comment: @JosephGreenbaum - Post your comment has an answer.  It by far is the BEST answer provided.  Allows the author to access said Windows machine from another Windows and OS X machine using pretty much the same exact client.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client if looking for the GUI way. Otherwise, via Terminal, it comes down to what @SecurityMatt said about using SSH.